# Display local variable in MVC grid view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, gridview, datagridview, grid

I want to calculate the age in view class without changing the model class  .

I already calculate the age .But it doesn't show in the web grid
So problem is how to display the variable in grid

```
<%    var age=(DateTime.Today.Year - item.BirthDay.Value.Year);

           @Html.DisplayTextFor(model => age);

      %>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i didn't find correct answer .finally came up with solution

```
     <%    var age=(DateTime.Today.Year - item.BirthDay.Value.Year);              

      %>
      <%=age  %>
```

Comment: Ideally you would use a ViewModel, this could then also contain other calculations you needed

Answer (score 0):

`(model => age)`

is it right? age is not a property of model. 
you should try

`@Html.TextBox("tbAge", age);`

Regards.

Comment: Yeah .(model => age) is not right .Thank you very much for your answer .But it does not work . Html.DisplayFor(model => model.BirthDay) .This work .But i need to calculate age

Comment: this is the way .i finally found a way to do

    
         <%    var age=(DateTime.Today.Year - item.BirthDay.Value.Year);              
                                 
          %>
          <%=age  %>